# Default implementations in coq’s Modules

Tags: module, coq

I have an interface that I want to implement several times:

```
Module Type I.
  Parameter a : A.
  Parameter b : B.
  Parameter c : C.
End I.
```

(and assume that each of `a`, `b` and `c` are actually many definitions).

An implementation would be

```
Module Imp1 <: I.
  Definition a : A := bar.
  Definition b : B := foo a.
  Definition c : C := baz a b.
End I.
```

Now it turns out that many implementations share the definition of `b` (which require `a`), but have different definitions of `c`.

How can I centralize the definition of `b`? Preferably without changing `I` or duplicating lots of definitions thereof?

(I imagine writing a module functor `BImp` expecting `a:A` as some kind of parameter, and then I can `Import (BImp a)`.)

Comment: In a sense, I want something like default implementations in Haskell’s type classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can outsource your shared definitions into a global definition (here `outsourced`) parameterized on the changing parts of your module (here `a`). I don't know if there is something like Haskell's default implementations.

```
Module Type I.
  Parameter a : A.
  Parameter b : B.
  Parameter c : C.
End I.

Definition outsourced (a:A) := foo a.

Module Imp1 <: I.
  Definition a : A := bar.
  Definition b : B := outsourced a.
  Definition c : C := baz a b.
End Imp1.

Module Imp2 <: I.
  Definition a : A := bar'.
  Definition b : B := outsourced a.
  Definition c : C := baz' a b.
End Imp2.
```

Comment: I thought about that, but does it scale? Note that each of `a`, `b` and `c` are actually many definitions. Or at least `b` and `c` are.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible/easy to do so, but did you try to define a module for the type B and embed a module inside a module ?

Comment: Right, but how would I best make that module parametric in `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate modules inside other modules. This forces you to duplicate part the modules' signatures, but not the proofs the modules contain.

```
Module Type PreorderSignature.
Parameter Inline type : Type.
Parameter Inline less : type -> type -> Prop.
Parameter Inline reflexivity : forall x1, less x1 x1.
Parameter Inline transitivity : forall x1 x2 x3, less x1 x2 -> less x2 x3 -> less x1 x3.
End PreorderSignature.

Module Preorder (PS : PreorderSignature).
Import PS.
(* Preorder facts. *)
End Preorder.

Module Type EquivalenceRelationSignature.
Parameter Inline type : Type.
Parameter Inline equal : type -> type -> Prop.
Parameter Inline reflexivity : forall x1, equal x1 x1.
Parameter Inline symmetry : forall x1 x2, equal x1 x2 -> equal x2 x1.
Parameter Inline transitivity : forall x1 x2 x3, equal x1 x2 -> equal x2 x3 -> equal x1 x3.
End EquivalenceRelationSignature.

Module EquivalenceRelation (ERS : EquivalenceRelationSignature).
Import ERS.
Module PreorderSignatureInstance <: PreorderSignature.
Definition type := type.
Definition less := equal.
Definition reflexivity := reflexivity.
Definition transitivity := transitivity.
End PreorderSignatureInstance.
Module PreorderInstance := Preorder PreorderSignatureInstance.
Import PreorderInstance.
(* Now your equivalence relations will inherit all the facts about preorders. *)
(* Other equivalence relation facts. *)
End EquivalenceRelation.

Module Type PartialOrderSignature.
Parameter Inline type : Type.
Parameter Inline less : type -> type -> Prop.
Parameter Inline reflexivity : forall x1, less x1 x1.
Parameter Inline antisymmetry : forall x1 x2, less x1 x2 -> less x2 x1 -> x1 = x2.
Parameter Inline transitivity : forall x1 x2 x3, less x1 x2 -> less x2 x3 -> less x1 x3.
End PartialOrderSignature.

Module PartialOrder (POS : PartialOrderSignature).
Import POS.
Module PreorderSignatureInstance <: PreorderSignature.
Definition type := type.
Definition less := less.
Definition reflexivity := reflexivity.
Definition transitivity := transitivity.
End PreorderSignatureInstance.
Module PreorderInstance := Preorder PreorderSignatureInstance.
Import PreorderInstance.
(* Now your partial orders will inherit all the facts about preorders. *)
(* Other partial order facts. *)
End PartialOrder.
```

And to flatten the module hierarchy a bit you can use the `Import` and `Parameter Inline` commands.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add `a : A` etc. to the module, to make the connection to my question?

Comment: @joachim-breitner. Updated the answer, but didn't have any good examples.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the example functions from my question. But that is fine as well, I guess.